# How can I make the last row undeletable

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview that displays your friends, and I'm making this table editable. You can add friends by tapping the last row, which says "ADD FRIEND". When you want to delete a friend, you tap edit on the navigation bar, and you can delete whichever row you want. Problem is: you can also delete the last row that says "ADD FRIEND". How can I make the last row undeletable? I dont want to show the "deletable" animation on the last cell (the red circle).

Code is pretty basic, see below.

.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FriendsListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSInteger totalRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]; //first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.

    if(indexPath.row == totalRow -1){
        //this is the last row in section.
        AddFriendIndexRow = totalRow-1;
        cell.friendName.text = @"+  ADD FRIEND";
    } else {
        cell.friendName.text = friendsList[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}




// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    [friendsList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"friendslist: %@", friendsList);


    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Comment: Look at the "editingStyle" delegate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use the `canEditRowAtIndexPath` data source method and do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView * _Nonnull)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull)indexPath {
    if (indexPath == //Last index path)
        return NO
    else return YES
}
```

You are returning NO for the last indexPath in your tableView and YES for all others. This will make all rows editable except for your last one.  More documentation can be found here on Apple's Site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: It would probably be better to return `YES` here for all rows but return the "Insert" editing style for the last row. This way the "Add Friend" row gets the green circled + icon while the rest of the rows get the red - icon.